# How do I switch between multiple locales with GNU gettext()? setlocale() is failing to achieve this

Tags: linux, rust, localization, gettext, ffi

My intention is to create a language-learning project that uses `gettext()` for its translations, showing each string in both the user's primary language and a secondary target language.

I am new to Rust and also to GNU `gettext()`. I am using [`gettext-rs`](https://crates.io/crates/gettext-rs) which appears to be a Rust foreign function interface that wraps the C `gettext()` implementation fairly directly. I don't believe my problem is Rust-specific but I haven't tested another language yet. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

It appears that the examples in `gettext()` documentation suggest that `setlocale()` is not required/advised, but my translations don't appear to work without a call to it. Furthermore, the locale string for the `setlocale()` function doesn't appear to be obeyed: the system locale is used instead.

Perhaps it is an inefficient approach, but I was first going to test a proof of concept for my project by switching locales with `setlocale()` to generate two different translations for the same `msgid` between `gettext()` calls. It appears that, because `setlocale()` doesn't obey the passed-in locale string, this approach is not working.

After installing Rust, I created a new project using the Terminal:

```
cd /home/timotheos/dev/rust/
cargo new two-locales
```

I updated `two-locales/Cargo.toml` to:

```
[package]
name = "two-locales"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
gettext-rs = "0.7.0"
gettext-sys = "0.21.3"
```

I updated `two-locales/src/main.rs` to:

```
extern crate gettext_sys as ffi;
use std::ffi::CStr;
use std::ptr;

use gettextrs::LocaleCategory;

// gettext_rs doesn't currently expose a way to call setlocale() with a null parameter.
// The plan is to later open a pull request that adds this function to their getters.rs:
pub fn getlocale(category: LocaleCategory) -> Option<Vec<u8>> {
    unsafe {
        let result = ffi::setlocale(category as i32, ptr::null());
        if result.is_null() {
            None
        } else {
            Some(CStr::from_ptr(result).to_bytes().to_owned())
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let new_locale = "en_GB.UTF-8";
    let domain_name = "two-locales";
    let locale_directory = "/home/timotheos/dev/rust/two-locales";
    
    // Specify the name of the .mo file to use, and where to find it:
    let locale_directory_path = std::path::PathBuf::from(locale_directory);
    let result_path = gettextrs::bindtextdomain(domain_name, locale_directory);
    if result_path.is_err() {
        println!("bindtextdomain() didn't work: {:?}", result_path);
    }
    else {
        let result_path = result_path.unwrap();
        if locale_directory_path != result_path {
            println!("bindtextdomain() worked but the output path didn't match: {:?}", result_path);
        }
    } 
    if gettextrs::textdomain(domain_name).is_err() {
        println!("textdomain() didn't work");
    }

    // Ask gettext for UTF-8 strings:
    let result_charset = gettextrs::bind_textdomain_codeset(domain_name, "UTF-8");
    if result_charset.is_err() {
        println!("bind_textdomain_codeset() didn't work: {:?}", result_charset);
    }
    
    let current_locale = getlocale(LocaleCategory::LcAll);
    let locale_str = String::from_utf8(current_locale.unwrap()).unwrap();
    println!("Current locale is {:?}", locale_str);

    use gettextrs::*;

    // This does not translate because the locale has not been set:
    println!("{}", gettext("Hello (ID)"));

    println!("Setting locale to {:?}", new_locale);
    let new_locale = setlocale(LocaleCategory::LcAll, new_locale.as_bytes().to_vec());
    if new_locale.is_some() {
        let new_locale = String::from_utf8(new_locale.unwrap()).unwrap();
        println!("setlocale() set the locale to {:?}", new_locale);
    } else {
        println!("setlocale() failed: try seeing if the specified locale is in `locale -a`");
    }

    // This does translate, but it is using system locale ("en_AU.UTF-8" and not the specified locale):
    println!("{}", gettext("Hello (ID)"));
}
```

I then generated the `.po` files for both `en_AU` and `en_GB` for testing:

```
cd two-locales
cargo install xtr
find . -name "*.rs" -exec xtr {} \; # Create messages.po from main.rs
cp messages.po messages_en_AU.po
mv messages.po messages_en_GB.po
```

I modified the contents (only changing the `msgstr`) of `messages_en_AU.po` to:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2022-08-13 05:49+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: ./src/main.rs:21
msgid "Hello (ID)"
msgstr "Hello (translated AU)"
```

and the contents (only changing the `msgstr`) of `messages_en_GB.po` to:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2022-08-13 05:49+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: ./src/main.rs:21
msgid "Hello (ID)"
msgstr "Hello (translated GB)"
```

then made these into `.mo` files in the directory:

```
mkdir en_AU/
mkdir en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/
msgfmt -v messages_en_AU.po -o en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/two-locales.mo
mkdir en_GB/
mkdir en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/
msgfmt -v messages_en_GB.po -o en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/two-locales.mo
```

so the final relevant directory structure is:

- `src/main.rs`
- `Cargo.toml`
- `en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/two-locales.mo`
- `en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/two-locales.mo`

and then I ran my software using:

```
cargo run
```

The output of this was:

```
   Compiling two-locales v0.1.0 (/home/timotheos/dev/rust/two-locales)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.56s
     Running `target/debug/two-locales`
Current locale is "C"
Hello (ID)
Setting locale to "en_GB.UTF-8"
setlocale() set the locale to "en_GB.UTF-8"
Hello (translated AU)
```

As seen from the output, the `setlocale()` call is required before `gettext("Hello (ID)")` will translate its passed-in string. When `setlocale()` is called, it *does* translate the string, but it grabs it from the `en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/two-locales.mo` file instead of the `en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/two-locales.mo` as I would expect.

Why doesn't my approach work? Is there a bug in `setlocale()` or am I missing something to make it correctly switch to the locale string specified?

I assume there might be some caching involved and `setlocale()` switching is not advised anyway. If my approach is incorrect, what is the best strategy for accessing GNU `gettext`'s `.po` or `.mo` files with multiple languages concurrently, ideally efficiently?

Any improvements to my Rust code are also welcomed.

For clarity, my system locale is `en_AU`. If I run `locale` in the Terminal then it outputs:

```
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_AU:en
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

and if I run `locale -a` in the Terminal then it outputs:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
fr_BE.utf8
fr_CA.utf8
fr_CH.utf8
fr_FR.utf8
fr_LU.utf8
POSIX
```

so I assume `en_GB.UTF-8` should be a valid locale to set using `setlocale()` (and it did output as if it succeeded).

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need `setlocale()` for switching locales. There is no other way. You have two options for that. In C they look like this:

```
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "fr_FR.UTF-8");
```

Or:

```
putenv("LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8");
putenv("LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8");
putenv("LANGUAGE=fr_FR.UTF-8");
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, ""):
```

None of these approaches is thread-safe because `setlocale()` is not thread-safe (the `xlocale` API is thread-safe).

Getting this to work platform-independently is a major nightmare because locale identifiers are not portable. My version above (lowercase language, uppercase region, uppercase codeset) works reasonably well across platforms, also on systems using GNU libc like yours.